Solution of a square root SDE
In my research I have a family of SDEs that frequently pop up and I can't find an analytical solution for them, nor can I sample from them exactly. For $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ the SDE is
\begin{equation}
{\rm d} X_t = a X_t {\rm d} t + b\sqrt{X_t} {\rm d}B_t.
\end{equation}
Importantly this is not a CIR process. I can solve this with a stochastic numerical integrator but then the process can go below zero, and I don't want to place an reflecting/absorbing boundary because it introduces bias. To this end, I have an idea of splitting the SDE into a deterministic component and a stochastic component, and then compose them using Strang/Lie-Trotter composition. The deterministic component is analytically solvable, but the stochastic part is problematic, i.e. I have trouble solving
\begin{equation}
{\rm d} X_t = b \sqrt{X_t} {\rm d}B_t,
\end{equation}
and this is the main reason why I'm writing this question. This is somewhat close to ${\rm d}X_t = {\rm d}t + 2 \sqrt{X_t} {\rm d} B_t$ which has a known solution, so I tried a few transformations. Namely, if I perform a Lamperti transformation I obtain the SDE
\begin{equation}
{\rm d} Y_t = -\frac{1}{2Y_t} {\rm d}t + {\rm d} B_t.
\end{equation}
If I solve this SDE, then
\begin{equation}
X_t = \left(\frac{b Y_t}{2}\right)^2.
\end{equation}
However, I cannot bring this SDE to any of the exactly solvable forms in Kloden and Platen's book, nor can I use the transformation outlined in the second part of the answer in how to do such stochastic integration $dS = a S^b dt + c S dW$?.
What I tried was transforming the "Lamperti" SDE with $f(y) = y^2$. Now $f'(y) = 2y$, $f''(y) = 2$, and by Ito's lemma we have
\begin{equation}
{\rm d} f(Y_t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} {\rm d}y + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} ({\rm d}y)^2 = 2Y_t (- \frac{1}{2Yt} {\rm d}t + {\rm d}B_t) + \frac{1}{2} 2 {\rm d}t = 2Y_t {\rm d}B_t
\end{equation}
I wonder if this is the same as
\begin{equation}
{\rm d} Y_t = 2 \sqrt{Y_t} {\rm d}B_t,
\end{equation}
because then it's a little closer (but not the same) to the exactly solvable SDE that I showed before, but I can't solve this either.
Does anyone have any hints?

As mentioned here How to solve the SDE: $dX_t = aX_t dt + b \sqrt{X_t} dW_t$ and https://hsrm-mathematik.de/WS201516/master/option-pricing/Cox-Ingersoll-Ross-Process.pdf, this is a type of CIR-model, which doesn't have any analytical solution, and it has an alternative representation:
$$X(t) = e^{-at} X_0 + b \int_{0}^{t} e^{-as} \sqrt{X(s)} dW(s)=e^{-at} X_0+I_{t}.(*)$$
So here you have a exponential decay plus a random variable $I_{t}$ with zero mean and variance
$$E[I_{t}^2]=b^2\int_{0}^{t} e^{-a2s} E(X(s))ds.(**)$$
In terms of simulating, it seems tricky because the square-root term is nonlinear and so even just a few iterations of Picard-iteration seem messy. So perhaps since (**) is linear in $X$, it might be a bit easier to replace $I_{t}$ by a Gaussian process $\tilde{I}_{t}\sim N(0, (**))$ and try to do a Picard-type simulation.
